# Can't connect to remote server with Fabric and SSH using key file

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

I'm trying to use a Fabric python script to log into the production server then run the 'ls' command remotely. Well I actually have lots of other commands to run, but I'm starting off with a simple list to get it working. My production server uses SSH and is locked down so it needs a private key file and password.

Now I've been reading up on some sites about how to get this to work, but can't get it to log in for some reason. I think it connects ok but a message comes up saying:

***Login password for 'root':***

So I enter my password (same as the one in env.password) and it just keeps popping up the message.

Here's my fabfile.py:

```
from fabric.api import *

env.use_ssh_config = True
env.hosts = ["myserver.net"]
env.user = "root"
env.key_filename = "/home/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa.ppk"
env.password = "mypassword"
env.port = 22

def testlive():
  run("ls")
```

Here's my SSH config in /home/myusername/.ssh/config:

```
Host myserver
  hostname myserver.net
  port 22
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.ppk
```

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Many thanks

Comment: If you just try logging in over SSH as `root` with that password, you get in?

Comment: As favoretti says, plus add `-vvv` to get debug information. Also try key-based over terminal first.

Comment: Testing the SSH separately from command line was very helpful thanks @favoretti and Jasper.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up testing the SSH config separately from the command line first to get that part working. I think there was a problem with the SSH keys as I had used PuTTY to generate them and that format may have been incompatible with the OpenSSH ones that Linux uses.

So first I made new SSH keys on my linux machine without a password for the private key which made two files for me id_rsa and id_rsa.pub. Then I copied the public key string from id_rsa.pub into the authorized_keys file on the production server. Then I tested from the command line. Once that was working I tested with Fabric.

So config changed to look like:

```
from fabric.api import *

env.use_ssh_config = True
env.hosts = ["myserver"]
env.user = "root"
env.key_filename = "/home/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa"
env.password = ""
env.port = 22

def testlive():
  run("ls")
```

Here's my SSH config in /home/myusername/.ssh/config:

```
Host myserver
  hostname myserver.net
  port 22
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Now works fine when I run `fab testlive` from the commandline.

Comment: The detail in `~/.ssh/config` is redundant (for fabric) if you set `env.use_ssh_config = False`, along with the host, the username, and the identity file in the fabfile.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred for us after hardening our servers agains Logjam for PCI compliance. Using https://weakdh.org/sysadmin.html as a reference, I had updated our /etc/ssh/sshd_config to include the line:

```
KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
```

As of 1.15.2, paramiko does not appear to support this elliptic key exchange algorithm. The weakdh.org page says that the non-elliptic `group14-sha1` diffie-hellman algorithm is not vulnerable to Logjam, so changing the line to...

```
KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
```

...allowed me to do Fabric deploys over SSH as well as maintaining PCI compliance.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: ssh-add ~/.ssh/aws_instance.pem

**File Name** : fabfile.py 
**To run from command prompt** : First add key and then run fab script

1] ssh-add ~/.ssh/aws_instance.pem
2] fab check_status

```
from fabric.api import run, env

env.hosts = ['myserver_name.in']
env.user = 'ubuntu'

def check_status():
    """
    Will show status for nginx service
    """
    run ("systemctl status nginx.service")
```